Why can't floating-point numbers in the line "scanf ("%. 3f ",&a);" be stored in the floating-point variable a with three decimal places retained?
Output is 0.000
Why does the output result look like this? What is its principle? Why can't floating-point numbers be stored?
Please help me answer my questions, thank you
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main(){
    float a;

    scanf("%.3f", &a);

    printf("%.f", a);

    return 0;
}


What is your input? What is your expected output? Why do you expect that output?

Also please note that there is almost no need to use float in normal applications. Use double and you will push problems like this in front of you (you will never get rid of the problems floating point have on binary systems).

Welcome to SO. You should always check the return value of scanf. If it does not successfully parse an input, you will use the corresponding variable without proper initialization causing undefined behaviour.

What input are you providing to the program?

%.3f is not a valid conversion specification for scanf.  Precision can be specified (.3 or merely .) only for the printf family of functions, not for the scanf family.

a = trunc(a * 1000.0) / 1000.0;

@Someprogrammerdude using double here should have exactly no effect on the output, so your advice seems a bit painted with overly broad strokes. Also, I maintain "normal" software and can assure you, "normal" software has plenty use cases for float. ;)

Both your format specifiers are invalid; %3f and %f would be valid. But the 3 in %3f specifies a number of characters, not decimals. ("Number of decimals" is a meaningless concept in binary floating point.)

@MarcusMüller, you're right that switching from float to double will not solve this problem, but it is nevertheless good advice to use double for floating point except where you really need the properties of float (usually the smaller storage size).

@JohnBollinger the smaller storage size and thus the better packability and thus the often highly developed ability of the compiler to vectorize operations, indeed.

@molbdnilo, %.f is a valid conversion specification for printf.  It means the same as %.0f (the promoted argument is a double, and it should be formatted in decimal notation with 0 digits to the right of the decimal point).

@JohnBollinger Cool. A day when I learn something is not entirely wasted.

"Output is 0.000" -- doubtful.  I could believe just "0", though.

Note well that there is a huge difference between storing floating point numbers and storing them with some specific precision.  All standard floating types in C have fixed precision (and variable scale, which is what the "floating" in "floating point" means).  And mostly they are represented in binary, not decimal, so that fixed precision is measured in units of binary digits (bits) not decimal digits.

%.3f is not a valid conversion specifier for scanf, as .3 is for specifying precision in output, not input. You can use %f.
With the invalid conversion specifier, the behavior is not defined by the C standard. Your scanf implementation might examine the string, not find any proper conversion to perform, and return without reading any input, likely with an error return code (EOF). Thus no value is assigned to a.

… three decimal places retained…

You cannot specify how many decimal places are retained in a float object. The format of float is fixed in each C implementation, most commonly as the IEEE-754 binary32 format, also called “single precision.” It has a significand (fraction portion) of 24 binary digits (bits), which is more than sufficient to identify any decimal numeral with three significant digits within the finite bounds of the format.
